# android: how to get all folders with names

Tags: android, image, gridview, directory, mediastore

Hi can somebody help me with my code?? I have a class which should show me folders on my SD card+ folders name, but all folders have same name, but each should have different. How can i implement it??

```
public class ThumbnailAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

// Context required for performing queries
private final Context mContext;

// Cursor for thumbnails
private final Cursor cursor;

private final int count;

String bucket;
String id;


public ThumbnailAdapter(Context c) {
    this.mContext = c;

    // Get list of all images, sorted by last taken first
    final String[] projection = {
            MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_ID,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME
    };
    String BUCKET_GROUP_BY =
            "1) GROUP BY 1,(2";
    String BUCKET_ORDER_BY = "MAX(datetaken) DESC";

    cursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            projection,
            BUCKET_GROUP_BY,
            null,
            BUCKET_ORDER_BY
    );
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

        int bucketColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME);

        int idColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_ID);


        do {
            // Get the field values
            bucket = cursor.getString(bucketColumn);
            id = cursor.getString(idColumn);


        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    count = cursor.getCount();
    Log.d("ThumbnailAdapter", count + " images found");
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return count;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

      LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(mContext);

      ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
      TextView mytext = new TextView(mContext);
     mytext.setText(bucket);
      imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_folder_icon);
      ll.addView(imageView);
      ll.addView(mytext);



    return ll;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably not setting your TextView `mytext` to change the text it displays - try the line:

`mytext.setText(projection[position]);`

I'm not quite sure how you are indexing your `projection` String array, but by just providing the right index (using the `position` variable in the `getView()` method, you should be able to change the TextView name correctly.

Comment: what i should put in position

Comment: position is automatically generated in the getView method. You should be able to call `position` on the array where you are storing your values for thumbnail and name

Comment: i can;t make mytext.setText(projection[position]); it shows me error

Comment: error-projection, can you say how it should be. what i need to add

Comment: what array are you storing the names in? I believe it's projection, but is it a 2-D array?

Comment: in String bucket i get my folder name

Comment: I don't see a `String` variable named `bucket`. There are `BUCKET_GROUP_BY` variables, but those seem to be sorting conditions. Do you know where your names/thumbnail paths are being stored?

Comment: i found how implement it. But i have another question, do you know how to make so, that when i push at my photo, how to make it full screen dize with zoom???

Comment: If this answer helped you, please mark this as the accepted answer. For your other question, I suggest you start another question to get more exposure and possibly better answers

Comment: i made it, but your answer didn't helped. i made: mytext.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME)));

Comment: do you know how to make so, that when i push at my photo, how to make it full screen dize with zoom???

Comment: @Paltroth you want to post that as a seperate question. I am not your individual guide to making your Android app work.